# Setting a shortcut icon to switch to another home screen in Nova Launcher Prime

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-5, nova-launcher

In [Nova Launcher Prime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher.prime&hl=en), is there any way to set a shortcut icon to switch to another home screen? When going to the left or right home screen, I would prefer to tap on some icon rather than having to swipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long-press -> Nova Action -> Jump to page. You can choose the icon by long-pressing on the shortcut after creation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would need to use a third-party automation app such as Tasker. Nova Launcher is listed in the *Go Home* section of [Tasker documentation](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/ah_index.html) as supporting the required action `Go Home`.

For example, you could create a shortcut icon to a Tasker task named *Switch to Right Home*. The *Switch to Right Home* task would contain the action `Go Home` with parameter `Page` set to `2` (possibly the right-most home screen depending on how many are displayed).

It is a variant of the [solution on this blog](http://thenowhereman.com/wp/?p=17816), where he provides instructions for switching the home screen based on device orientation.